# Erro ao executar projeto JSF pelo eclipse

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, mvc, spring

Boa noite , estou tentando executar um projeto no eclipse, porem o tomcat esta me lançando a seguinte exceção. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

```
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:pta' did not find a matching property.
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Feb 6 2018 23:10:25 UTC
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         8.5.28.0
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 7
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            6.1
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_161-b12
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.28
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.28
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\endorsed
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;.]
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 1083 ms
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service [Catalina]
fev 25, 2018 8:57:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
fev 25, 2018 8:58:01 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
fev 25, 2018 8:58:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/pta]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/pta]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@8b1c8e4]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4868)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@24939586]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:139)
    ... 13 more

fev 25, 2018 8:58:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

fev 25, 2018 8:58:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

fev 25, 2018 8:58:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
fev 25, 2018 8:58:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
fev 25, 2018 8:58:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Stopping service [Catalina]
fev 25, 2018 8:58:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
fev 25, 2018 8:58:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: Por favor, leia o guia de [ask] para ver como pode melhorar sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

> *Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)*

Ou seja, algum dos JARs do classpath da sua aplicação, do tomcat, ou até mesmo da JDK, está corrompido.

Sugiro o seguinte:

1. Tente reinstalar o tomcat para deixá-lo limpo e faça o deploy de um hello world com JSP nele. Se isso der errado, então há algo seriamente errado no seu ambiente e talvez seja o caso de reinstalar até a JDK.
2. Se o passo 1 der certo, faça o deploy da sua aplicação e veja se funciona. Se funcionar, então o seu problema apenas desaparece e está resolvido.
3. Se o passo 2 não der certo, então há algo de errado na sua aplicação, provavelmente no classpath. A sugestão seria baixar cópias novas de todos os JARs e certificar-se de que não há conflitos de classpath.
4. Se mesmo após reinstalar o tomcat (e talvez até a JDK) e baixar novamente todos os JARs, e mesmo assim continuar dando esse erro, diga quais são os JARs da sua aplicação, de onde você os baixou e como é que você configura o tomcat, e daí vamos tentar identificar qual é o problemático e como substituí-lo.